# probability question

Tags: probability

June's coffee was very famous. On average, it sold 10 cups of coffee per hour. Find the probability that: 
a) exactly 12 cups of coffee were sold in 2 hours
b) more than 3 cups of coffee are sold in an hour

Comment: What work have you done on the problem so far?

Answer (score 2):

The usual probabilistic  model for this sort of situation leads to the Poisson distribution. Just because it is in a sense the default model does not make it the only possible model. Coffee sales are likely to show very strong sensitivity to the hour of the day, The only thing one can say for sure is that if this is an exercise, we are expected to assume that sales in an hour have a Poisson distribution.

The parameter (mean, often called $\lambda$), for sales in one hour, is $10$. For $2$ hours, it is $20$.

On the assumption that the Poisson provides a reasonably good model, the probability that exactly $12$ cups are sold in $2$ hours is $e^{-20}\dfrac{20^{12}}{12!}$.

For more than $3$ cups in $1$ hour, it is easiest to find the probability of $3$ or fewer cups, and subtract the result from $1$. The probability of $3$ or fewr cups in an hour is
$$e^{-10}\left(1+\frac{10^1}{1!}+ \frac{10^2}{2!}+\frac{10^3}{3!}          \right).$$